# addNamedDestination not inserting destinations into new PDF

Tags: java, pdf-generation, itext

I'm manipulating a PDF available from https://www.census.gov/content/dam/Census/library/publications/2015/econ/g13-aspef.pdf. Part of the manipulation is to copy the pages from the original PDF to a new PDF, and also to copy the named destinations. The iText Java API method addNamedDestinations isn't inserting the destinations into the new PDF.

Below is my code segment which is based on the example in the book iText in Action, 2nd edition.

```
try {
    PdfReader reader1 = new PdfReader("C:\\Temp\\g13-aspef.pdf");
    Document doc = new Document();
    PdfCopy copy2 = new PdfCopy(doc, fileout);
    doc.open();
    reader1.consolidateNamedDestinations();
    int n = reader1.getNumberOfPages();
    for (int i = 0; i < n;) {
        copy2.addPage(copy2.getImportedPage(reader1, ++i));

    }
/* myDests indeed includes all 23 destinations appearing in the original PDF. */
    HashMap<String,String> myDests = SimpleNamedDestination.getNamedDestination(reader1, false);
/* Use addNamedDestinations to insert the original destinations into the new PDF. */
    copy2.addNamedDestinations(myDests, 0);
    doc.close();
 } catch (IOException e) {
     System.out.println("Could not copy");
 }
```

However, when I open the created PDF, the pages are there, but not the destinations. Why don't I see the destinations in the new PDF?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Named destinations are not something you can *see* (there are no visual indications of named destinations), so please explain why you think the named destinations aren't there.

Comment: In Acrobat Pro (and possibly other PDF readers), we can view named destinations (View > Show/Hide > Navigation Panes > Destinations). For example, regarding the original PDF I indicated above, I see that one of the destinations is `text_G13.indd:.1752:25`, which opens on page v. In the copied PDF made with the above code, the navigation pane is blank and does not show those original destinations.